# flexbox: create a space to the left for my elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to get this result

[image]

The elements to the left are positioned correctly.

Currently, I get this:

[image]

I would like to create a space to the left.

I can use the propriety  `margin-left: 127px;` and my problem is solved, but I think that there is a best solution with the flexbox?

```
.top-bar .top-bar-left {  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start; 
    margin-left: 127px;
}
```

Thanks

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

a {
    color: #454545;
    transition: .3s;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
    color: #F7CAC9;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.top-bar {   
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    background: #343148;
}


.top-bar .top-bar-left {  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start; 
   
}


.top-bar .text { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
    flex-direction: row; 
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.top-bar .text i {  
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-right: 5px;
}


.top-bar .text h2 { 
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
}


.top-bar .text p {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}


.top-bar .text:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.container-fluid { 
    max-width: 1472px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display:flex;

}

.top-bar .top-bar-right { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}


.top-bar .social a { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 35px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.top-bar .social { 
    display: flex;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 0;
    justify-content: flex-end; 
}


.top-bar .social a:first-child { 
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.top-bar .social a:hover { 
    color: #092a49;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>YOOGA</title>

        <!-- Google Font -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- CSS Libraries -->
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Template Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- Top Bar Start -->
        <div class="top-bar"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="top-bar-left">
                    <div class="text">
                      <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                      <h2>8:00 - 9:00</h2>
                      <p>Mon - Fri</p> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone-alt"></i>
                        <h2>+123 456 7890</h2>
                        <p>For Appoitment</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="top-bar-right">
                  <div class="social">
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Top Bar End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What logic do you want to achieve? Just space from left and right, or adaptive space, or something else?

Comment: Did you try `justify-content: space-between` or `justify-content: space-evenly` (applied to the parent element)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>YOOGA</title>

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS Libraries -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Template Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
</head>
<style>
    body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

a {
color: #454545;
transition: .3s;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
color: #F7CAC9;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
}


.top-bar {   
position: relative;
height: 35px;
background: #343148;
}


.top-bar .top-bar-left {  
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start; 
flex:1 1 0;

}
.top-bar .text { 
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;  
flex-direction: row; 
height: 35px;
padding: 0 10px;
text-align: center;
border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.top-bar .text i {  
font-size: 13px;
color: #FFF;
margin-right: 5px;
}


.top-bar .text h2 { 
color: #eeeeee;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 13px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin: 0;
}


.top-bar .text p {
color: #eeeeee;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}


.top-bar .text:last-child {
border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.container-fluid { 
max-width: 1472px;
justify-content: space-between;
display:flex;

}

.top-bar .top-bar-right { 
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-end;
flex:1 1 0;
}


.top-bar .social a { 
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 35px;
height: 100%;
font-size: 16px;
color: #ffffff;
border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.top-bar .social { 
display: flex;
height: 35px;
font-size: 0;
justify-content: flex-end; 
}


.top-bar .social a:first-child { 
border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.top-bar .social a:hover { 
color: #092a49;
background: #ffffff;
}
.textdiv{
margin:auto;
display: flex;
}
</style>
<body>
    <!-- Top Bar Start -->
    <div class="top-bar"> 
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
                <div class="textdiv">
                <div class="text">
                <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                <h2>8:00 - 9:00</h2>
                <p>Mon - Fri</p> 
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone-alt"></i>
                    <h2>+123 456 7890</h2>
                    <p>For Appoitment</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="top-bar-right">
            <div class="social">
                <a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Top Bar End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to add new div before text div and add flex:1 1 0 to left and right top bar div

Comment: Thank you Animesh. It was what i wanted.

Comment: What is the question?  You should only specify the smallest possible piece of code that helps to demonstrate the  issue you are having, then be clear about what you want the output to look like, versus the current output.  StackOverflow is built to help others find answers to similar queries so a specific question like this doesn't really help anyone but the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with grid on parent element, with one more empty div in the middle

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

a {
    color: #454545;
    transition: .3s;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
    color: #F7CAC9;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.top-bar {   
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    background: #343148;
}


.top-bar .top-bar-left {  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start; 
   
}


.top-bar .text { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
    flex-direction: row; 
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.top-bar .text i {  
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-right: 5px;
}


.top-bar .text h2 { 
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
}


.top-bar .text p {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}


.top-bar .text:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.container-fluid { 
    max-width: 1472px;
    justify-items: center;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr auto 1fr;
}

.top-bar .top-bar-right { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    
}


.top-bar .social a { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 35px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.top-bar .social { 
    display: flex;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 0;
    justify-content: flex-end; 
}


.top-bar .social a:first-child { 
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}


.top-bar .social a:hover { 
    color: #092a49;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>YOOGA</title>

        <!-- Google Font -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- CSS Libraries -->
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Template Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- Top Bar Start -->
        <div class="top-bar"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="top-bar-left">
                    <div class="text">
                      <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                      <h2>8:00 - 9:00</h2>
                      <p>Mon - Fri</p> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone-alt"></i>
                        <h2>+123 456 7890</h2>
                        <p>For Appoitment</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div></div>
                <div class="top-bar-right">
                  <div class="social">
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Top Bar End -->
</body>
</html>
```